# Scraping Twitter Data: API Failed (Error 403)

Tags: r, twitter

I am trying to learn how to scrape tweets from Twitter (using R). I have a twitter account and registered for the API. I got all necessary keys that seem to be required (api key, api secret, access token, access secret, bearer token).

I am now following this tutorial here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtweet/vignettes/auth.html

I first entered this line:

```
auth <- rtweet_app()
```

And then I entered my bearer token - when I try to view this object, it looks like this:

```
> auth
<Twitter bearer token>
```

I tried to run a query as suggested in the tutorial:

```
 df <- search_tweets("#rstats", token = auth)
```

But this returns the following error:

```
Error: Twitter API failed [403]
Check error message at https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/error-troubleshooting
```

I tried to search this error on Twitter, but it does not seem very informative on how I can troubleshoot this:

```
# https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/error-troubleshooting
    The request is understood, but it has been refused or access is not allowed. An accompanying error message will explain why.
```

**Can someone please help me further troubleshoot this error?**

Note: I did not get error 401 which would have indicated that I was not successfully authenticated.

Thanks!

Here is my session info:

```
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rtweet_1.0.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] prettyunits_1.1.1 withr_2.5.0       digest_0.6.29     crayon_1.5.1      R6_2.5.1          lifecycle_1.0.1   evaluate_0.15    
 [8] httr_1.4.4        rlang_1.0.2       progress_1.2.2    cli_3.3.0         curl_4.3.2        vctrs_0.4.1       ellipsis_0.3.2   
[15] rmarkdown_2.14    tools_4.1.3       tinytex_0.40      hms_1.1.1         xfun_0.30         yaml_2.3.5        fastmap_1.1.0    
[22] compiler_4.1.3    pkgconfig_2.0.3   askpass_1.1       htmltools_0.5.2   knitr_1.39       
>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my_auth <- rtweet::create_token()` works better but it's deprecated. But it works!

Run `my_auth <- rtweet::create_token()` without arguments, and you should see a login window in your browser (or confimation is you are already logged in).
In a result you should get a new variable in your environment "my_auth". Like on the image:
[image]

and auth file in dir (on linux): `~/.config/R/rtweet`.

Then you can make query like:
`obama_tweets <- rtweet::get_timeline(c("barackobama"), n = 3, parse=T, token=my_auth)`

---

You can also use function `auth_sitrep()`  to see which auth file is valid, because auth files created with `rtweet_app()` are (almost) empty (you can also check directory `~/.config/R/rtweet`).

You can also reuse, saved (automatically) auth file with `auth <- readRDS("~/.config/R/rtweet/default.rds").`

Comment: Suppose I wanted to find out tweets that contain the word "obama" - is there some way I can do this? Thank you so much!

Comment: I am reading this document here (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtweet/rtweet.pdf) and there is a function "search_tweets" but apparently this function can only retrieve tweets from the past 6 to 9 days...

Comment: @stats_noob ```search_tweets``` also works, but you have to have proper auth object, example ```tweets <- search_tweets("#somehashtag", n = 100, type = "recent", include_rts = FALSE, token=proper_auth)```

Comment: @ user1660210: thank you so much for this! n = 100 means the 100 most recent tweents? thanks again for everything!

Comment: @stats_noob yep, `n = 100` means `100 most recent tweets`. your welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a "R" programmer, but I found an article maybe that helps you :)

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/scraping-and-analyzing-tweets-in-r-62582e2f4543